# How to subtract the first column from every column of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing very simple subtraction and I cannot get it right. I'd like to subtract the first column from every column of an array. For example:

```
winner=
[1,2,3]
[2,3,5]
[3,5,7]
```

I'd like to get the result like this:

```
[0,1,2]
[0,1,3]
[0,2,4]
```

Here is the error, I am not sure how to do it.

```
winner.shape
(5, 3)

winner_difference=winner-winner[:,0]
winner_difference

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-d385252ef2de> in <module>
----> 1 winner_difference=winner-winner[:,0].T
      2 winner_difference

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,3) (5,)
```

Comment: The error message shows different code from what is seen above. Please clarify what code you are actually using, by providing a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient method, taking advantage of numpy broadcasting:

```
output = winner - winner[:, 0, None]
```

Output:

```
>>> output
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 2, 4]])
```

Comment: yes richard,it works. I was trying to achieve similar broadcasing thing, so I have use winner[:, [0]] instead of winner[:, 0]. why? Thanks

Comment: Because, `[:, 0]` is almost like you're selecting a single column from the grid, whereas `[:, [0]]` is like you're selecting a copy of the grid with only that column...one is the column itself, the other is the grid with the colum...

Comment: `[:, 0]` returns `[1, 2 3]` which can't be used in broadcasting, while `[:, [0]]` returns `[[1], [2], [3]]` which _can_ be broadcasted.

Comment: Thank you Richard! I appreciate it, Merry Christmas!

Comment: @richardec it's still better to do `winner - winner[:, 0, None]` to avoid a copy.

Comment: Oh wow, sweet!! I'll not forget that awesome trick, @user3483203. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty trivial thing to achieve with list comprehensions.

```
>>> winner = [[1,2,3], [2,3,5], [3,5,7]]
>>> [[y - x[0] for y in x] for x in winner]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 4]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for:

```py
winner - np.vstack(winner[0])
```

Comment: Typically though, you could use more advanced indexing such as my answer: `winner[:, [0]]` ("select from columns the 0th element")